# working out safe insert/update order for tables with fk/non-null constraints in place

Tags: sql, relational-database

I have a collection of tables I want to replicate from one database to another with both mandatory fields and FK constraints in place.

I can use a topological sort to work out the correct order once I've removed cycles, but is there any good method for working out where to optimally split a record into two separate insert-update taking into account foreign key and non-null constraints?

Comment: If your db supports it, you can just delay the fk constraints until commit. Laking that functionality, you can disable the constraints and re-enable them (if your db can do this within a transaction - IIRC Oracle used to auto-commit on DDL – not sure about new versions)

Comment: This is specifically with constraints in place and active I'm afraid.